# APC installed but not running on Gentoo

Tags: apache-2.2, gentoo, alternative-php-cache

EDIT: i've reinstalled with Ubuntu server and it's not working as it should. Was never comfortable with Gentoo anyway ;)

I'm a Gentoo noob so please be gentle :)

I'm trying to install APC on a Gentoo (2006) based LAMP stack provided on a VPS by my host. I've run

> emerge -av php5-dev/pecl-apc

to install it, and it appears to be compiled etc properly. EDIT: Here's the last several lines of the emerge: http://pastebin.com/MMjtjhrz

I've added these lines to /usr/local/lib64/php5/php.ini:

```
[apc]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_size = 32
```

and restarted Apache (which restarts fine, suggesting okay config), but APC doesn't run. Can't see it in phpinfo() or using php -m.

EDIT: not sure if it matters, but the .so files are located in /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/, which seems a bit bizarre. Suhosin is in there too, but it's not running either.

Can anyone help? Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you sure that you edited the correct php.ini file - sometimes there can be several of them. Try php -i | grep php.ini to see which one is active.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's the right one, that command gives /usr/local/lib64/php5/php.ini

Comment: Edit your post and append some last lines when emerging `apc`? Did you see `apc.so` in the extension directory?

Comment: How did you compile Apache and PHP? The normal path is `/etc/php/apache2-php5.x/php.ini`.

Comment: I didn't - it came preinstalled on the VPS. It's a Gentoo installation customised by the ISP - although to what extent it's different from a standard install I don't know.

Comment: Here's the last several lines from the emerge: http://pastebin.com/MMjtjhrz

Comment: `grep extension_dir /usr/local/lib64/php5/php.ini`?

Comment: extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ :/

Comment: `grep -lr "extension=apc.so" /usr/local/lib64/php5/`?

Comment: I don't get any output from that!

Comment: I've added extension=apc.so to php.ini and it's working now! So simple, silly me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

> extension=apc.so

to php.ini did the trick!